# What chemical or biochemical agents do plants use to inhibit each other's growth?

Tags: botany, allelopathy

As I just learned, allelopathy is the action by which plants regulate the growth of other nearby plants.

I have hear of ethylene is a general signal for growth and fruit ripening in particular, but I would like to hear about more specific compounds or proteins that are known to be allelopathic agents and how specific can they be - lots of plants ignore each other and just grow over each other.

@AlanBoyd [has pointed me to a journal](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/do-plant-plant-interactions-inhibit-growth), but as its not open content, I'm hoping for a next level review of the mechanisms and actors in this topic...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic example is juglone from Black Walnut tree roots. This [review](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed050p782) from 1973 discusses juglone and allelopathy, inhibiting growth of other trees. This 1961 [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14006337) describes juglone's effects as able to sedate or at depress movement of *Daphnia magna*, leopard frogs, perch, catfish, goldfish, mice, rats and rabbits. That led to work testing juglone on cancer cells.

Answer (score 4):

As with the massive variety of compounds that serve to protect plants against insect and animals, resulting in a wide range of poisons, antibiotics and other natural insecticides, allelopathic compounds are highly varied with different methods of action: some merely prevent germination while others are effectively herbicides.

One example is *Alliolaria petiolata*. In that species the allelopathic substance is not known, but is thought to ahve a fungicidal effect that [impedes mycorrhizal development](http://www.plosbiology.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pbio.0040140), which would seriously affect the development of many species.